# Memory leak in realloc of (void *) to concatenate string

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

Given a struct object with a void pointer `(void *) value` that is initialized using malloc to hold a string `"chapt"`.
Afterwards, using `realloc` to make enough memory to concatenate another string.

```
/* Standard Imports */
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h> 
#include <assert.h>

struct generic_type
    {
        void *value;                            
        void (*add)(struct generic_type, int);  
    };

/* Function Declarations */
static void TestRun();
static void AddNumToString(struct generic_type element, int num);

#define TEST_ARRAY_SIZE 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TestRun();
    
    (void) argc;
    (void) *argv;

    return 0;
}

static void TestRun()
{
    struct generic_type element;

    element.value = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
    assert (NULL != element.value);
    element.value = strcpy(element.value, "chapt");
    element.add = AddNumToString;

    element.add(element, 10);
    free(element.value);
}

static void AddNumToString(struct generic_type element, int num)
{
    size_t num_length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", num);
    size_t str_length = strlen((char *)(element.value));
    size_t new_length = str_length + num_length + 1;
    char *num_string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (num_length + 1));
    
    sprintf(num_string, "%d", num);
    
    element.value = realloc(element.value, sizeof(char) * new_length);
    assert (NULL != element.value);
    
    element.value = strcat(((char *)(element.value)), num_string);
    
    free(num_string);
}
```

This implementation results in the correct output but has a memory leak:

```
==29031== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29031== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29031== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29031== Command: ./a.out
==29031== 
==29031== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==29031==    at 0x4C30D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29031==    by 0x1088EB: TestRun (teststructs.c:40)
==29031==    by 0x108862: main (teststructs.c:22)
==29031==  Address 0x522d040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 6 free'd
==29031==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29031==    by 0x108999: AddNumToString (teststructs.c:52)
==29031==    by 0x1088DF: TestRun (teststructs.c:39)
==29031==    by 0x108862: main (teststructs.c:22)
==29031==  Block was alloc'd at
==29031==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29031==    by 0x10887B: TestRun (teststructs.c:34)
==29031==    by 0x108862: main (teststructs.c:22)
==29031== 
==29031== 
==29031== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29031==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==29031==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 17 bytes allocated
==29031== 
==29031== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==29031==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29031==    by 0x108999: AddNumToString (teststructs.c:52)
==29031==    by 0x1088DF: TestRun (teststructs.c:39)
==29031==    by 0x108862: main (teststructs.c:22)
==29031== 
==29031== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29031==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==29031==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29031==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29031==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29031==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29031== 
==29031== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29031== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It seems like the problem lies with the `realloc` line but I can't seem to see the problem with it.

Allocating enough memory during the initialization and avoiding `realloc` solves the problem but I rather know why this isn't working at this point.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE]. What is `struct sgeneric`? How is the function called? How are you initializing all relevant pointers? Where does the invalid access happen? Is it a read or a write? Why do you put `(char *)` everywhere? `has a memory leak:` Please show what valgrind is showing you. There should be whole stack, including additional information. You just posted info about some addrses. And as a side note, just `snprintf` into `element.value`, there is no need for `num_string`.

Comment: The code you've shown looks okay to me, so the bug may be somewhere else.  I agree that you should create a minimal example.

Comment: `memory allocation of (void *) is free'd outside of the function` How so? The function `StringIntCat` takes the `struct sgeneric` argument *by value* so the pointer realloc'd to `element.value` is never returned to the caller.

Comment: Updated the question I hope that's more clear

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly code in FreeStructWithString using a pointer value from before the realloc call.

Comment: Note that "Invalid free" isn't a memory leak; it's much worse.  "Memory leak" is when you fail to free something that was allocated; it wastes memory but doesn't affect the program's correctness.  But here you have freed something that wasn't allocated; this causes undefined behavior and may break your program in severe or subtle ways.

Comment: This still isn't a minimal reproducible example.  We're looking for a complete program that can compile and run.

Comment: `strcpy(element.value, "chapt\0");` That explicit null char is not needed.  String literals always have an implicit null char at the end.  `strcpy(element.value, "chapt");` will do the same thing.

Comment: `\0"` - one of `\0` gets ignored, just remove the `\0`. `ws8_main.c:100` looks like a rather short file - you might consider posting it whole. (I see that your function pointers take the struct by value. You do not call realloc and modify `sgeneric::value` in `void (*add)(struct sgeneric,..)` by chance?)

Comment: `element.value = strcpy(element.value, "chapt\0");` This is weirdly misleading. There is no need to assign to `element.value` its own unchanged value, which is what `strcpy` returns. Ditto re. `strcat` below.

Comment: @NateEldredge editted a working code with relevant functionality

Comment: Why not use `asprintf` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AddNumToString` is passed its `element` argument by value, so that it gets a *copy* of the object that was passed to it.  This means that when you do

```
element.value = realloc(element.value, sizeof(char) * new_length);
```

the original pointer contained in the `element` is freed, but the new one is stored in the copy.  The copy is lost when `AddNumToString` returns, so the newly allocated space is leaked.  And worse, the object in the caller remains unchanged; in particular, it still contains the original pointer which has now been freed.  So when it's eventually freed (not shown in your current code), that's a double free, which is bad.

You probably want to have `AddNumToString` take a pointer to `struct generic_type` instead, so that it can actually modify the object in place.

Comment: I tried checking the address and length of `element.value` before and after the function call, it returned the same address and the length increased by the correct length. That really put me off. Thanks for the detailed answer.